# Terraform with Github Actions Pattern

Tags: git, github, terraform, github-actions

I am trying to implement Github Actions for Terraform Plan and Apply using Github Pull Request and Merge features.

What I am not able to achieve is, reusing the workflow for every new component in the project.

For example, I have to add a new microservice in the project, I have created a Terraform module as below,

```
#new-microservice.tf
module "new-microservice" {
  source = "",
  name   = "foo",
  nlb    = true,
  few other details
}
```

So, when a new microservice needs to be added into the project, anyone can create new TF file with module block by changing the values of the attributes.

```
#one-more-microservice.tf
module "one-more-microservice" {
  source = "",
  name   = "bar",
  nlb    = false,
  few other details
}
```

So far, so good. Issue arrives when I want to isolate each of this microservice's resource states.

Each of this TF files will go into a separate directory in the Git repo so that TF state will be isolated.

But, with Github Actions, workflow yaml should be kept in .github/workflow directory of the Git repository.

How can I find the directory which has changes in the pull request and run the workflow inside that directory?

I tried searching in the Github Actions Marketplace, couldn't find anything concrete.

I don't want to create multiple jobs inside the plan and deploy workflow yaml files, one for microservice.

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky because you're basically saying that you want one workflow to trigger on multiple repository pushes which is not currently a thing in github actions

Option 1:
Create a [Workflow Template](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/sharing-workflow-templates-within-your-organization) that all it does is spin up on a service push and sends a [workflow dispatcher](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhook-events-and-payloads#workflow_dispatch) event. You basically make an api call that triggers that workflow. The only caveat is that as of right now organizational workflow templates only work on public repos.

Option 2:
Keep track of each service last build commit. This will allow you do to scans. The problem with this is that you will need to setup a [workflow on a cronjob](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onschedule) that will then go through a list of all your repos in your organization, and do the commit diff. If there is a commit diff available then you know to do what you need to do for your deployment. [How to get list of organization repos](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-organization-repositories)